# Expand all input fields to size of value or remove all input fields with javascript.

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, forms

I have an extremely large form with around 200+ input fields, once the form has been completed you can view it in the admin section (copied code from main section).

I really don't want to have manually go through and delete every input field. Is there a way to expand all input fields to the size of the value or input after page load or remove then input tags all together leaving just the value?

Comment: Could you show us (a snippet) of code as this is impossible to answer until we understand what you're doing?

Comment: You can loop through all known fields and check if they are set, if you have all field names in an array for example. Or if the names of the fields are similar like `input_1`, `input_2` etc. you can also loop easily through them. You should add some code to the question, how your form structure is and what you already tried to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to change all input fields to native text:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("input").each( function(index)
  {
    $(this).replaceWith("<p>"+$(this).val()+"</p>");
  }
  );
});
</script>
```

This will then remove all input tags all together leaving just the value (with a < p> tag around it )

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wKvPg/

Comment: that worked perfect. nice little hack will save me days!! thanks veda, legend

Answer (score 0):

if you just pasted the code it means that your code is mostly html so in that case i would use a text editor like notepad++ it has a find and replace function which supports regex you can use that

[Download Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

On the future i recommend you avoid copy/pasting code and implement them as functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can have hundred or more inputs with `same name` and `different values`:

```
<input type="text" name="values[]" value="val1" />
<input type="text" name="values[]" value="val2" />
```

Just loop it all:

```
foreach ($_POST['values'] as $key => $val) 
{
   print "Key = " . $key . " Value = " . $val . "<br />";
   // another actions
}
```

Or access directly:

```
$val1 = $_POST['values'][0]; // 'val1'
$val2 = $_POST['values'][1]; // 'val2'
```

Hope that helps.